# お目にかけますのは <- is it correct

Tags: politeness

I found this in my textbook.

ただいまより**お目にかけますのは**小学生によるバンド演奏です。

[image]

Is it strange ? Is it more polite than お目にかけるのは　？

PS.Sorry for my note

Answer (score 4, accepted):

お目にかける is a humble expression of 見せる.

1. ただいまよりお見せするのは小学生...
2. ただいまよりお目にかけますのは小学生...

Both are correct and #2 is more modest than #1.