# Who is the subject of もらう here?

Tags: grammar

The below is the description of a girl wearing glasses

> 肩までの長さがある黒髪には、ゆるい内巻きの癖があった。先ほどかけてもらった眼鏡越しに見える瞳は、心なしか憂いを帯びているようにも見える。

I'm uncertain about the subject of this verb かけてもらった. It is either 眼鏡 or 瞳.

Comment: The subject of もらった is the speaker and that of かける is the girl. Did you mean to ask what もらった modifies?

Comment: @aguijonazo I forgot to mention that the girl put on glasses by herself. She didn't get somebody to do it for her.

Comment: @aguijonazo Wait, I give it more thought and think you are right...

Comment: So you did mean “subject”? In any case, the speaker is being grateful the girl put on the glasses (on her own or otherwise). Neither 眼鏡 nor 瞳 has such a feeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject of かけてもらう is neither 瞳 nor 眼鏡 but **the speaker** ("I"). The speaker probably asked her to wear the glasses before this scene (先ほど), and that was beneficial to the speaker (the speaker may be a 眼鏡好き).

> (私は彼女に)眼鏡をかけてもらった。
> I had her put on glasses.
> She put on glasses (for me).
>
> **(私が彼女に)**先ほどかけてもらった眼鏡
> the glasses **I** had **her** put on a moment ago
>
> (私が彼女に)先ほどかけてもらった眼鏡越しに見える瞳
> her eyes I can see through the glasses I had her put on a moment ago

Note: Looks like there are only two people in this scene, but technically speaking, if there is a third person who likes meganekko, the subject of かけてもらう could be that third person.

Answer (score 0):

## Assuming you're **not** literally asking for the "subject" (as in subject/predicate):

*Apparently this was a totally wrong assumption*

---

Sometimes it's challenging to identify the subject in such construct. But this one is easy - it's the 眼鏡, because "かけてもらった" works against a pair of 眼鏡 better than against 瞳:

---

> 先ほどかけてもらった眼鏡越しに見える瞳は、心なしか憂いを帯びているようにも見える。

The eye(s) (I can) see through the glasses that (someone) put (on him/her), kinda seems to possess sadness.

- What did someone put on her? Answer: Someone put **眼鏡** on her.
- What seems to possess sadness? Answer: The **瞳** seems to possess sadness.

---

Expressions like [目にかける](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77150/%e3%81%8a%e7%9b%ae%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8b%e3%81%91%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e3%81%ae%e3%81%af-is-it-correct) or 目をかける do exist, but the context and the existence of 眼鏡 decreases the probability of 瞳 being the subject of かける to near zero.

Comment: Are you really saying the subject of かけてもらった is 眼鏡? "眼鏡(は|が)かけてもらった" is a correct sentence, but this means 眼鏡 has its own will and is saying "Yay thanks for wearing me!".

Comment: @naruto If you're asking if I was serious, yes I was. I didn't assume OP was asking for the *subject* in terms of textbook subject/predicate 101, I mean look at how the question was written. Now, I do wonder if such interpretation of *subject* and sticking to it was plain wrong to a point it may confuse future readers, or grossly flexible that it may add value somehow. What do you think?

Comment: I'm sorry, my comment was harsher than it has to be. So you assumed OP was actually asking about the *object* of かける? The question said "subject" twice, and OP is not a beginner who may mix subjects and objects, so I took the question literally. (BTW the downvote is not mine)

Comment: Oh come on stop apologizing for constructive criticism. The whole SE system is designed to **encourage** voting up/down and commenting for the benefit of the community. Not harsh at all. I'll just edit my answer to avoid confusion for future readers. But speaking of the future, one day people might just read this post through AI glasses that actually have consciousness...